# Java thread concept

Tags: java, c, multithreading, operating-system

I'm inexperienced in using threads and I wanted to check if I understand their implementation in Java and other programming languages well enough.

Is the fact that a class is called thread misleading?
I understand threads as an abstract concept which is a set of steps done by the processor that have an order and a meaning.
A java thread object however(as well as classes and structs form other programming languages) does not represent a thread entirely, as it passes control to monitors and does not execute the whole abstract thread.
Am I correct? Or am I understanding threads incorrectly?
(Obviously, I've read several definitions along the way including wikipedia but I'm still uncertain)

Also, are OS system processes(although implemented in C structs) similar to Java threads?

Comment: C has threads, which work in a similar fashion to Java's (barring that C isn't using classes and objects).

Answer (score 2):

The Thread object does represent a thread, in as much as it gives you a handle by which you can control a thread. Obviously the object is "special" in that it instantiates an actually running thread of execution, but it does represent that thread. The thread's run method (or the runnable it calls) defines the sequence of operations that that thread will execute and determines how long the thread will run for, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand threads as an abstract concept which is a set of steps done by the processor that have an order and a meaning.

That's not how I see it.  A thread the administrative framework required to execute independent code.  This can be kernel threads, user threads, or in this case VM threads.  I'm not sure what you mean by "order and a meaning" but a thread can execute any code.  To quote [this page](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/4_Threads.html):

> A thread is a basic unit of CPU utilization, consisting of a program counter, a stack, and a set of registers, ( and a thread ID. )

Good definition.

> A java thread object however(as well as classes and structs form other programming languages) does not represent a thread entirely, as it passes control to monitors and does not execute the whole abstract thread.

I'm not sure I understand your point.  The `Thread` object is Java's way to administer the independent entity.  It manages the stack frame, helps with VM scheduling and administration, and is tied closely with the native thread structures and also the OS scheduler.  In terms of Java, the `Thread` object certainly is a thread although to be technical maybe you can say that it is a thread after it is started.  But either way the term is not misleading -- at least not to me.

This is the same way that a Java `File` represents a file on disk.  Sure, it's not technically a file but to Java it is the class that manages access to the disk file.  Same with `Socket`, `InputStream`, `Console`, and any other class that is tied to a outside OS entity.

> Also, are OS system processes(although implemented in C structs) similar to Java threads?

Uh, sort of?  Not sure what you mean by "system process".  Maybe you are talking about kernel threads?  Regardless, the answer depends highly on the OS in question.  Not all OS' are written in C obviously.  Certainly the JVM works with the native side of Java and the OS to schedule and manage the threads.  After a `Thread` object has been started, with most OS', there is a 1-to-1 relationship between the Java class and a OS managed user thread.